# Turning Display Alerts off in PowerPoint from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am writing a macro that opens and closes a PowerPoint Presentation from Excel.
Now I have the issue that when I am trying to save the PowerPoint file I get a pop up Message Box. To take care of that issue I used:

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

However this works in some cases, as I loop through multiple Presentations but not in all. So I tried instead this:

`pptPres.Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

But this just caused the Display Alerts to **always** pop up.

So I tried to replicate that using

`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

which did not work. So I am quite confused what I am doing wrong. I need to turn the `DisplayAlerts` off otherwise my macro is stopped.

The issue occurs as I am opening a PowerPoint with macros so a `*.pptm` file which on saving I am asked whether or not to save with macros.

This is my current code, maybe you can replicate the issue:

```
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Set pptApp = CreateObject("powerpoint.Application")

Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(strPfad & strDat, False, True, True)

pptPres.Application.DisplayAlerts = False


strFirma = "Test123"
pptPres.SaveAs strPfad + "\Berichte" & "\" & strFirma & ".pptx"
pptPres.Close
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.displayalerts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powerpoint's [`Application.DisplayAlerts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.displayalerts) is slightly different. It has two options: `ppAlertsAll` and `ppAlertsNone`.

Try `pptApp.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone`. Note that you have a mix of early- and late-binding and probably should be consistent. If you go with late-binding, `ppAlertsAll`'s corresponding value is `2`, and `ppAlertsNone`'s corresponding value is `1`.

Thanks to [`@Matthieu Guindon`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mathieu-guindon) for pointing out that since you're running this from Excel, `Application` refers to `Excel.Application`, which is not your instance of PowerPoint. Hence `Application.DisplayAlerts` will not affect PowerPoint's alert setting at all. You want to work with `pptApp`, the instance of PowerPoint.

Comment: Excellent. I would add that when you're hosted in Excel, an unqualified `Application` member call is referring to the host `Excel.Application`, not PowerPoint's. The `pptApp` qualifier is critical here.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon absolutely, will add.

Comment: I figured that just `Application.DisplayAlerts` would refer to Excel that's why I tried the other one, but as I did not get an Error I was confused why it did not work. Anyways your solution works just fine. I am actually consitent in earl/late binding but in testing I was not. Thanks for the heads up anyways.

Comment: @Nils `As PowerPoint.Presentation` would be illegal without a reference to the PowerPoint library... and late-binding calls into a referenced library is just ...don't do that ;-) FWIW `CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")` should be `New PowerPoint.Application`. Late-binding is all about `Object` and `Variant`, nothing to do with how objects are created. `CreateObject` is a very roundabout way to go about creating an instance of a class the compiler is already aware of.

Comment: Ahh okay, so instead I should declare pptPres just as an Object? Thanks, I really did not know about that.

Comment: No keep it `As PowerPoint.Presentation`, but replace `CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")` with `New PowerPoint.Application`.

Comment: @Nils if you declare `As Object`, then you can remove the reference to the PPT type library. All member calls against `Object` are late-bound (i.e. resolved at run-time) and written blindfolded (without intellisense or any compiler assistance), thus prone to run-time error 438 and typos that `Option Explicit` can't save you from. Prefer early binding if possible.

Comment: Okay thank you so much, I will look out for that in the future. Do you happen to have a great article on that topic on your hand? If not I will search for one myself :)